# How to have functions pass arguments with the same overloads?

Tags: typescript, overloading

I am trying to create a function passes its arguments to another function. Both of these functions need to have the same overloads.

```
function original (a: number): boolean;
function original (a: string, b: string): boolean;
function original (a: number | string, b?: string): boolean {
  return true;
}

function pass (a: number): boolean;
function pass (a: string, b: string): boolean;
function pass (a: number | string, b?: string): boolean {
  return original(a, b);
}
```

This does not work.

> Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2345)
> input.tsx(4, 10): The call would have succeeded against this implementation, but implementation signatures of overloads are not externally visible.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAZgrgdgxgLgSwPZQARIE4IOYKgQwBtUAKfALlSggFsAjAUwwEpK6klCH8oBuUSLEQp0WXAWJlKAZzhYo2ADSo6MuXmysVHLj37ho8ZGkw48RUhSq1GGVAB9Us%20UpUB%20NS63tO3NAG9QVFQMBjgIDDQ5CAZ9AF9QAUNhNAAHfGlpS0pqeiZvHT99QSMRdMzsp3UFZVUqrzZCvSShY1RyrKlrPLtHZw1aj3qNAt8eVECQYNDwyNEzCTJa5nigA)

Comment: You can't. You'd have to expose the inner type of `original` as an overload.

Comment: Please keep in mind that once you overloaded your `original` function,  this type signature `function original (a: number | string, b?: string): boolean` (the last one) is not exposed to outer world. You may consider duplication of this `function original (a: number | string, b?: string): boolean` like here https://tsplay.dev/mqQy2m

Comment: Tip: Read the error message very carefully. For anyone finding this question your types will obviously be different. But you may just need to add more combinations of the overloads. The error messages may help you see what's missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just declare your `pass` function as being of the type of the `original` function using the [typeof](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html#handbook-content) operator, e.g.

```js
function original (a: number): boolean;
function original (a: string, b: string): boolean;
function original (): boolean {
  return true;
}

let pass: typeof original =  () => {
  return true;
};

pass(5);         // all good
pass('a', 'b');  // all good
pass(45, 'b');   // error here
```

[Playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/LAKAZgrgdgxgLgSwPZQARIE4IOYKgQwBtUAKfALlSggFsAjAUwwEpK6klCH8oBuUSLEQp0WXAWJlKAZzhYo2ADSo6MuXmysVHLj37ho8ZGkw48RUlvaduaAN6hUqDAzgQMaORAb6AvqFAuOFQAB3xpaUo4AE8QhiQwUTMJVABeJxJmNIA%20VAcQJxc3D1QvH1BffVAwiJIAVmZ9GukSAHJ8VuVWulbG6vCWgBY6rp6%20kCA)

Comment: Okay, but how do you do this for a class method?

Answer (score 3):

Add extra overload:

```
function original<
  A extends number | string,
  B extends A extends string ? string : undefined
>(a: A, b: B): boolean;
```

Now it looks like:

```
function original(a: number): boolean;
function original(a: string, b: string): boolean;

function original<
  A extends number | string,
  B extends A extends string ? string : undefined
>(a: A, b: B): boolean;

function original(a: number | string, b?: string): boolean {
  return true;
}

function pass(a: number): boolean;
function pass(a: string, b: string): boolean;
function pass(a: number | string, b?: string): boolean {
  return original(a, b); // Works
}

const t1 = original(1); // Works
const t2 = original("foo", "foo"); // Works
const t3 = original(1, "foo"); // Works: gives an error as expected
const t4 = original("foo"); // Works: gives an error as expected
```

You no more need the second overload `function original(a: string, b: string): boolean` but you may still leave it for better readability of the code.

[Playgroun](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=65&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABHATjA5jMBDANgCmwC5EwQBbAIwFMUBKEyuOXa7MAbgChRJYFkaTDgLFEAZyhow6ADSJKJSdPQMFzVu249w0eElQYseADxdEiAIKJqADyjUwAE3GkKNFIgA+EqVjnmiABCNvaOLlahDs6uyv6IAPy+Kogk4E7UwFjUTlwAfIQklvKKwWpMLGycXDp8+oJGIoVuVLTeyf4lCUp+MuUaVYgA3oEo1FAgKEhSINTcAL41vHoCAA7Y4uLNZK30jANatStI65vNcTIlPSr9lYfL-CcbW2I7Hu0XcgrdHX37d0gRhYxhMpg1hHhCCU6BxEAB6OGIADqqAA1uIuIsuBAEJJEFAAIyIAC84OMBAJMPhiJRKHR2NxUHxACYSWSmgAiYDMDnyLk8qkI5FojE4sB4qAAZjZhghFL53LgHMFNJFJEwADdqK52DYUChUIgNqFVtRoDkGeKmVAACwyoTk-D8pUq4V08TqmBanVIWgGzzGuym825IA)

Comment: Thanks. That's the correct answer, cleaner than hacking with `typeof original`

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but a different option. Just reference the signature and return type of `original` directly, instead of re-implementing them.

```js
function original (a: number): boolean;
function original (a: string, b: string): boolean;
function original (): boolean {
  return true;
}

function pass(
  ...args: Parameters<typeof original>
): ReturnType<typeof original> {
  return original(...args);
}
```

Intellisense knowns well enough to pull in the overloaded signatures, so you'll get relevant information when you type `pass(`. Plus you only need to maintain the original function.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, the implementation of function overloads receives the loosest type, 'any' or 'unknown'. But 'any' will make you lose the type (all related variables will become type of 'any), so 'unknown' is the only choice.
Why the implementation receives the loosest type?

You overload the function just because you want the function to accept different types/numbers of arguments. But, how do you know the type of the args passed in when the function is called? You don't know, you have to do some type-checking first.

```
function original (a: number): boolean;
function original (a: string, b: string): boolean;
function original (a: unknown, b?: unknown): boolean {
  return true;
}

function pass (a: number): boolean;
function pass (a: string, b: string): boolean;
function pass (a: unknown, b?: unknown): boolean {
  if(typeof a === "number" && typeof b === "undefined"){
    return original(a);
  }
  if(typeof a === "string" && typeof b ==="string"){
    return original(a, b)
  }
  return false; // maybe, depends on your logic 
}
```

Since the type signature of the implementation function is not externally visible, you won't get the `pass(unknown, unknown)` signature, only the two signatures above the implementation will be suggested.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a solution which doesn't use type assertions and doesn't change or add any overload signatures to either function: use an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression) to create both functions, where the functions have the weaker signature inside the IIFE's "private" scope, but the stronger signature outside.

```
interface OriginalSignature {
  (a: number): boolean;
  (a: string, b: string): boolean;
}

const [original, pass] = (function(): [OriginalSignature, OriginalSignature] {
  function original(a: number | string, b?: string): boolean {
    return true;
  }
  function pass(a: number | string, b?: string): boolean {
    return original(a, b);
  }
  return [original, pass];
})();
```

Tests:

```
// OK
original(1);
original('a', 'b');
pass(1);
pass('a', 'b');

// errors
original('a');
original(1, 'b');
pass('a');
pass(1, 'b');
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPJWAc1HANgZSxDjAFcoUBvAWAChlkAKOALmRFIFsAjaASjbcA9kNwQ4IANx0GzNgGcwGEJgA0ybgqWhMAjSLETptAL506CISEXIA2kIzZiudQAc48+QF1kAXiYwpCAIYMBWjHq26Fg4BEQk5BDq0U54hJjEZBQ+NPTIgcGhVsgOMc5y7Fy8UMgAPsiKymoaAPxaTXrCouIgyLkMDBRZvUqkEMYMZnkFIWG97p4VHDzQdQ3aKurcbesdggY9fTIDQ+S9pam4zFt8E8hTgxDDdhexbh7exiZ8EcZ0APT-NAAaTor3KAEZbmDHLFGAByODw9Tw7jw6G0BbyRhQ4xYhFIlFojEAoHQKAOeQwsp4Ano4zg2kQon0uj4xGszEfHEsjFAA)

Answer (score -4):

Cast to any in implementation ;). With overloaded signatures you are sure nothing else than allowed arguments will be there.

```
function original (a: number): boolean;
function original (a: string, b: string): boolean;
function original (a: number | string, b?: string): boolean {
  return true;
}

function pass (a: number): boolean;
function pass (a: string, b: string): boolean;
function pass (a: number | string, b?: string): boolean {
    return original(a as any, b as any); // here, you are sure only 
    // expected arguments may appear - so the cast operation is safe.
}
```

Alternatively use named tuples instead of overloading (the effect is similar to overloading).

```
function original(...args: [a: string, b: string] | [a: number]): boolean {
  return true;
}

function pass (...args: [a: string, b: string] | [a: number]): boolean {
  return original(...args);
}
```

Comment: I had to use this workaround until I figure out the problem of my overload :P